# Reading Contract Events

Tags: contract-development, events, ethereumjs

i have an promlem readen a Hash from ethereum logs.

When a user Mints a token, i fire a mint event:

```
  event Mint(address indexed _to, string indexed _hash, uint256 _tokenId);
```

Example for _hash = RbvxkRUzS3lOQ-OVU41u9BdJrDrIKq96vBMYHOmOVlY

The following code reads the event

```
 nftContract.on("Mint", (to, hash, tokenId) => {
      console.log("Event Mint:");
      console.log("to:", to);
      console.log("hash:", hash.hash);
      console.log("tokenId:", tokenId);
    
  });
```

TokenId and to address are read correctly, but the hash looks like this:
0xbbc277db6a0ee632a8c4804807799f9ab68cfa129a494172db5e288c5626b1df

At this point, I don't know how to convert the string back to its original value (RbvxkRUzS3lOQ-OVU41u9BdJrDrIKq96vBMYHOmOVlY).

Can someone help me here please?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [documentation](https://0xbbc277db6a0ee632a8c4804807799f9ab68cfa129a494172db5e288c5626b1df) about (indexed) events.

> You can add the attribute indexed to up to three parameters which adds them to a special data structure known as “topics” instead of the data part of the log. A topic can only hold a single word (32 bytes) so if you use a reference type for an indexed argument, the Keccak-256 hash of the value is stored as a topic instead.

In your case, `_hash` is of type `string` which is a reference type. Therefore the topic `hash` will be set to `keccak256(_hash)`.

You can see if with the following example :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Example {

  event TestEvent(string indexed _hash);

  function testFunction() public {
    emit TestEvent("RbvxkRUzS3lOQ-OVU41u9BdJrDrIKq96vBMYHOmOVlY");
  }
}
```

Where `hash` in the event log has value : `0x3bac3a5ed85f033e6a5a73512770c0084a9b6472c5d94ceb3904e22fadaa63a6` which is exactly the output of `keccak256("RbvxkRUzS3lOQ-OVU41u9BdJrDrIKq96vBMYHOmOVlY")`. (You probably wrote the wrong value when redacting your question, hence the mismatch in your post)

You can either not set `indexed` to `_hash` and read it from the log data, or convert your hash to hexadecimal to fit it in a `bytes32` variable (or less depending on your size), as long as your hash function outputs a value of at most 64 characters, allowing it to fit in the log topics.

I hope that answers your question.